# Generate a perfectly normally distributed sample of size n in R

Tags: r, normal-distribution, generate

I would like to generate a sample of mean = 0, sd = 1 and size n = 100 which distribution is as normal as possible. Using rnorm alone returns a lot of variability.

The only way I found was to average multiple rnorms.

`rowMeans(replicate(10000, sort(rnorm(100, 0, 1))))`

This returns a rather satisfying result, but I'm not sure it's the most efficient way of doing it.

---

### EDIT:

I don't want the mean and sd to be strictly equal to 0 and 1, but rather, the distributin to "look" like a normal distribution (when plotting the density curve).

It seems that the qnorm method works worse than the "average" method:

```
# qnorm method
x <- qnorm(seq(.00001, .99999, length.out = 100), mean=0, sd=1)
plot(density(x))

# average method
x <- rowMeans(replicate(10000, sort(rnorm(100, mean=0, sd=1))))
plot(density(x))
```

[image]
[image]

I would be pleased with a deterministic solution returning results close to the average method in a more efficient way.

---

### EDIT 2 : Possible solution

Based on the answers, the following seems to work, adjusting the bounds relatively to n:

`x <- qnorm(seq(1/n, 1-1/n, length.out = n), mean=0, sd=1)`

Below a comparison of the qnorm and average methods for different values of n:

```
par(mfrow=c(6,2))
for(n in c(10, 20, 100, 500, 1000, 9876)){
  x <- qnorm(seq(1/n, 1-1/n, length.out = n), mean=0, sd=1)
  plot(density(x), col="blue", lwd=2)

  x <- rowMeans(replicate(10000, sort(rnorm(n, mean=0, sd=1))))
  plot(density(x), col="red", lwd=2)
}
```

[image]

Comment: See my edited solution - the bounds 0.01 and 0.99 avoid the hump.

Comment: Using `qnorm` isn't "a sample of mean = 0, sd = 1 and size n = 100", its creating a regular set of points transformed by the inverse density function of the Normal distribution.

Comment: I agree @Spacedman - but that seemed to be what the OP was after based on his sampling strategy.  Using `qnorm` is basically the limit of all the averaging he is doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the bayestestR package:

```
library(bayestestR)
x <-  rnorm_perfect(n = 100, mean = 0, sd = 1)
plot(density(x))
```

[image]

Comment: Note that this function will be renamed as `distribution_normal()` in the next version :)

Answer (score 6):

Are you trying to create 100 numbers with an approximate normal distribution with mean exactly zero and sd exactly one? Do this:

Start roughly:

```
> X = rnorm(100)
```

Shift them:

```
> X = X-mean(X)
```

Scale them:

```
> X = X/sd(X)
```

Check it:

```
> mean(X)
[1] -7.223497e-18
```

near enough

```
> sd(X)
[1] 1
```

bang on.

This is the same as what the `scale` function does:

```
> X = rnorm(100)
> mean(X)
[1] -0.007667039
> sd(X)
[1] 0.9336842
> sx = scale(X)
> mean(sx)
[1] 1.437056e-17
> sd(sx)
[1] 1
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want a deterministic solution, this should work

```
qnorm(seq(0.01, 0.99, length.out = 100))
```

Note that `qnorm(0)` gives $-\infty$ and `qnorm(1)` is $\infty$, so you need to find some reasonable bounds.

For `n=100`, the bounds 0.01 and 0.99 appear to work best.  If you want the bounds to be farther out for the deterministic solution, you'd need to increase `n`.

Answer (score 0):

Low discrepancy sequence?
halton, faure, sobol, hammersley: example:

```
library(randtoolbox)

sequence <-sobol(n=100, dim = 1, init = TRUE, scrambling = 0, seed = 4711, normal = FALSE)
mean(sequence)
[1] 0.4982031
sd(sequence)
[1] 0.2860574

#trial with prng
set.seed(1) 
sequence2 <- runif(100)
mean(sequence2)
[1] 0.5178471
sd(sequence2)
[1] 0.2675848
```

with the same amount of points low discrepancy sequence are better than pseudoramdom generator, keep in mind that for uniform random sample the true mean is 0.5, sd is  0.2886751  (sqrt(1/12)), look at the numbers.

```
(mean(sequence) - 0.5)/0.5   #  -0.0008984375
(mean(sequence2) - 0.5)/0.5  #  -0.008923532
(sd(sequence) - sqrt(1/12))*sqrt(12)
[1] -0.009067992
(sd(sequence2) - sqrt(1/12))*sqrt(12)
[1] -0.07305918
```

~10 times better, try with other seed if you do not believe it

```
ks.test(sequence,"runif")

    One-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test

data:  sequence
D = 0.96268, p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: two-sided

> ks.test(sequence2,"runif")

    One-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test

data:  sequence2
D = 0.93956, p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: two-sided
```

Now some balancing:

```
    sequence <- c(sequence, 1.0 - sequence)  #balancing the mean = use antithetics
    #or if you want (sequence <- sequence - mean(sequence))
    normal_sample <- qnorm(sequence)
    normal_sample <- normal_sample/sd(normal_sample)
    plot(normal_sample)
```